# Retrieve descendant (path) of tree base of multiple values

Tags: sql, sql-server, tree, hierarchical-data

I have a self reference table to store hierarchical values in order to show up them in a TreeView or so on ,according to James Crowley article ([Tree structures in ASP.NET and SQL Server](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/4633/tree-structures-in-aspnet-and-sql-server/))

```
Our table would look something like this:

Id  ParentId      Name        Depth    Lineage
1   NULL        Root Node       0       /1/
2   1           Child A         1       /1/2/
3   1           Child B         1       /1/3/
4   1           Child C         1       /1/4/
5   2           Child D         2       /1/2/5/
```

To get path of a node (for example id=5) he suggest following query against table

```
SELECT *
FROM dfTree
WHERE (SELECT lineage
       FROM dfTree
       WHERE id = 5) LIKE lineage + '%'
```

result would be :

```
Id  ParentId      Name        Depth    Lineage
1   NULL        Root Node       0       /1/
2   1           Child A         1       /1/2/
5   2           Child D         2       /1/2/5/
```

**And Is Acceptable**

But how about to have a result set when there are multiple IDs which i want to have their path ? therefore for example in above example instead of Id=5 i would like to pass multiple values something like this :

```
SELECT *
FROM dfTree
WHERE (SELECT lineage
       FROM dfTree
       WHERE id IN (5,6,8,9)) LIKE lineage + '%'
```

But the above statement make no sense and it is invalid sql server expression
How could i solve this problem ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want records where the ids that you are looking for are the top-level parent, the child or anywhere in the lineage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query...

```
SELECT DISTINCT T2.*
FROM 
    (
        SELECT lineage
        FROM dfTree
        WHERE id IN (4, 5)
    ) T1
    JOIN dfTree T2
    ON
        T1.Lineage LIKE T2.Lineage + '%'
```

...returns the following result on your test data:

```
Id   ParentId   Name        Depth   Lineage
1    NULL       Root Node   0       /1/
2    1          Child A     1       /1/2/
4    1          Child C     1       /1/4/
5    2          Child D     2       /1/2/5/
```

As you can see, all paths are "merged" together - for example, the path component `Id=1` belongs to both the path: `/1/4/` and the path: `/1/2/5/`, yet exists in the result set only once.

---

One the other hand, if you **do** need to distinguish between different paths, you'd need to do something like this:

```
SELECT T2.*, T1.Id LeafId
FROM 
    (
        SELECT id, lineage
        FROM dfTree
        WHERE id IN (4, 5)
    ) T1
    JOIN dfTree T2
    ON
        T1.Lineage LIKE T2.Lineage + '%'
```

Result:

```
Id   ParentId   Name        Depth   Lineage    LeafId
1    NULL       Root Node   0       /1/        4
4    1          Child C     1       /1/4/      4
1    NULL       Root Node   0       /1/        5
2    1          Child A     1       /1/2/      5
5    2          Child D     2       /1/2/5/    5
```

In this case, each path is identified by its leaf. This assumes there are no diamond-shaped dependencies (i.e. this is a real tree and not just any [DAG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph)); if there *are*, then you'd need to use `T1.Lineage` instead of `T1.Id` to identify the path.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running SQL Server 2005 or higher you could move the subquery to a CTE:

```
; with cte as (
    SELECT lineage
    FROM dfTree
    WHERE id IN (5,6,8,9)
)
SELECT d.*
FROM dfTree d
inner join cte on cte.lineage like d.lineage + '%'
```

Or just restructure the subquery:

```
SELECT d.*
FROM dfTree d
inner join (
    SELECT lineage
    FROM dfTree
    WHERE id IN (5,6,8,9)
) s on s.lineage like d.lineage + '%'
```